# Customizar link permanente diretamente no post não funciona

Tags: php, wordpress

Quando faço uma postagem no Wordpress, tem a opção na parte superior de customizar o link permanente, quando tento alterar esse link permanente não é permitido, trabalho com alguns blogs em Wordpress e só um em específico está dando esse erro. Poderiam me ajudar?

Versão do Wordpress: 3.6.1
Estrutura customizada: `%category%/%post_id%`

Porém, quando acesso a postagem e tento customizar o link permanente eu não consigo.

Comment: Qual o erro? Seja específico, deixe conosco a mensagem, etc.

Comment: Boa tarde Guilherme, não apresenta erro nenhum, simplesmente quando clico na caixinha da URL pra alterá-la não permite, é como se o texto estivesse desabilitado.

Comment: Posta um print de como está, talvez vendo a imagem alguém consiga perceber alguma coisa diferente.

Comment: http://imageshack.com/a/img836/884/cn81.png

Comment: Esse é o problema, não existe nenhum erro aparente, nada, simplesmente não consigo alterar o texto dentro do input text como nós fazemos nos outros sites que administramos.

Comment: Alguma luz galera??? Ainda permaneço com o problema.

Answer (score 2):

Pra quem tiver o mesmo problema que eu tive, a resolução é simples.

Basta alterar em Estrutura customizada para:

%postname%/%post_id%

Pronto, com isso vc consegue editar as URLs das postagens.